# Freezing header and first column using data.table in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, data.table

I have a Shiny app that yields a data table, but I can't freeze the first column and the headers, so the table is hard to read as you go down or across.  Is there anyway to freeze the panes?  I've tried searching but have found nothing.

Comment: Following recent Shiny update, you might try here and see what sorting options are available https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert

Answer (score 15):

Interesting question and now thanks to the recent update of Shiny to `data.tables 1.10.2`
it is alot easier to use the various plug-ins and extensions. For your question the [FixedHeader](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/) extension seems ideal. To add this extension we need to include the relevant `JavaScript` and `CSS` file (see http://cdn.datatables.net/):

```
tagList(
  singleton(tags$head(tags$script(src='//cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/2.1.2/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js',type='text/javascript'))),
  singleton(tags$head(tags$link(href='//cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/2.1.2/css/dataTables.fixedHeader.css',rel='stylesheet',type='text/css')))
)
```

`data.tables` has an option `initComplete` which allows us to stipulate a callback once table is drawn etc.

```
function(settings, json) {
     new $.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader(this, {
                                            left:   true,
                                            right:  true
                                          } );
                                        }
```

We will use a modified version of the `iris` data set adding an index and some random data at the end to show left to right scrolling:

```
library(shiny)
myData <- cbind(list(index = row.names(iris)), iris
                , rep(list(row.names(iris)), 10))
names(myData)[7:16] <- paste0("randomData", 1:10)
runApp(
  list(ui = fluidPage(
    tagList(
      singleton(tags$head(tags$script(src='//cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/2.1.2/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js',type='text/javascript'))),
      singleton(tags$head(tags$link(href='//cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/2.1.2/css/dataTables.fixedHeader.css',rel='stylesheet',type='text/css')))
    ), 

    dataTableOutput("mytable")
  )
  , server = function(input, output, session){
    output$mytable <- renderDataTable(myData,
                                      options = list(
                                        pageLength = 50,
                                        initComplete = I("function(settings, json){
                                          new $.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader(this, {
                                            left:   true,
                                            right:  true
                                          } );
                                        }")
                                      )
    )
  })
)
```

so in the image we can see we are scrolled down to record 8 and across some ways but the header and the first column (our added index column) are still visible.

[image]

Comment: Happy to help if the answer solves your question consider marking it as accepted by ticking it.

Comment: Many thanks for your help!  Is there a way to also freeze the header of the first column, so it's visible as I scroll to the right?

Comment: Following `dataTables` documentation and your excellent detailed answer, I tried the `FixedColumns` plugin in one of my shiny apps. I included `fixedcolumns/3.0.2` css and js files as well as `dataTables 1.10.4` css and js files in my header  and included the `initComplete` in my options with a minor change as follows: `function(settings, json) {
     new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns(this, { } ); }`. However when I ran the app, the table kept displaying the `processing...` message and did not load as expected. I'm currently using the latest shiny release, 0.11. Thoughts?

Answer (score 12):

FixedHeader is now (2021) compatible with FixedColumns. [See table](https://datatables.net/download/compatibility)

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
runApp(
  list(ui = fluidPage(
    
    dataTableOutput("mytable")
  )
  , server = function(input, output, session){
    Rows <- c(1:30)
    for (y in 1:15){
      x<-y-1
      assign(letters[x+1],runif(5, 0, 1))
    }
    x <- data.frame(Rows, mget(letters[1:15]), row.names=NULL) 
    x<- x[2:15]
    output$mytable <- renderDataTable(
      DT::datatable(x, rownames=FALSE,extensions = c('FixedColumns',"FixedHeader"), 
                    options = list(dom = 't', 
                                   scrollX = TRUE, 
                                   paging=FALSE,
                                   fixedHeader=TRUE,
                                   fixedColumns = list(leftColumns = 1, rightColumns = 0))
      )
    )
  } 
  )
)
```

Implemented:

> 2021-09-10: FixedColumns 4.0.0