# How to freeze in Shiny a row using DT table

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, dt

I've been wondering for some days if it's possible to fix two rows in order not to sort and filter them since are not data (first and second rows).

I know that fixing columns can be done but I'm not interested on it, I'm interested in fixing the first and second row and looking in DT documentation, I've not find anything about it.

Can someone please help me?

Thank you
[image]

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26228786/freezing-header-and-first-column-using-data-table-in-shiny

Comment: How's not making them rows but part of the header? You can style them such that it looks like them being part of the body.