# Issue with UI side of Shiny app with data table

Tags: r, shiny

I am in the process of creating a shiny app for a process at work and am struggling to figure something out on the UI side of the app. I would like to display a data table next to a sidebar menu containing options for the app. The issue is that when I do so, the data table is pushed down below the sidebar panel instead of beside it (see the original data tab).

I found a work around as seen in the suggested tab, but that comes with its own issues. I need to be able to lock the column headers while scrolling through the app and when the data table is inside the box element, I am unable to find a way to do so.

Here is the code to a simplified version of the app.

```r
library(shiny)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinythemes)
library(sortable)
library(reactlog)


ui<- dashboardPage(
  #this gives you the name displayed on the tab
  dashboardHeader(title = "HHS Resin Purchasing 0.99"),
  #this gives you your sidebar (page) options
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Original Data", tabName = "original"),
      menuItem("Suggested", tabName = "suggested")
    )
  ),
  #this is the body of the webpages
  dashboardBody(
    #this gives you the body options that are displayed on every page
    sidebarPanel(width = 2,
                 h2("Menu Options"),
                 h4(strong("Upload Data:")),
                 fileInput("file", "Data", buttonLabel = "Upload..."),
                 textInput("delim", "Delimiter (leave blank to guess)", ""),
                 numericInput("skip", "Rows to skip", 0, min = 0),
                 h4(strong("User Options:")),
                 selectInput("plant", "Select a Plant", choices = 
                               c("All")),
                 dateInput("latest_date", "Select the latest W_LEAD date in the data",
                           value = Sys.Date()),
                 numericInput("avg_multiple", "Multiple of Daily Useage for Cuttoff",21, min = 1, max = 50),
                 h4(strong("Download Options:")),
                 actionButton("complete_orders", "Analysis for plant orders complete"),
                 actionButton("complete_checks", "Mid month check complete"),
                 downloadButton("downloadData1", label = "Download Suggested Orders...", class = "btn-block"),
                 downloadButton("downloadData2", label = "Download Flags...", class = "btn-block"),
                 downloadButton("downloadData3", label = "Download Full Suggested Orders Data...", class = "btn-block")
                 
    ),
    #This is the actual data that fills those page options listed above
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "original",
              DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "preview1")
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "suggested",
              box(title = "Suggested Orders",width = 9, status = "primary", height = "auto",
                  solidHeader = T, dataTableOutput("preview2"), style = "max-height:800px; overflow-y: scroll;overflow-x: scroll;")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$preview1 <- renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(iris, options = list(searching = T, pageLength = 20, lengthMenu = c(5,10,15, 20))
  })
  
  output$preview2 <- renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(iris, options = list(searching = T, pageLength = 20, lengthMenu = c(5,10,15, 20))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Help in fixing either of the issues outlined above would be very appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using the column() function will support your first question of the datatable moving under the sidebar sidebarPanel. Please see example below.

I think the second request of freezing the row header in the datatable can be resolved with the advice found at [Freezing header and first column using data.table in Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26228786/freezing-header-and-first-column-using-data-table-in-shiny/40294323)

```
library(shiny)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinythemes)
library(sortable)
library(reactlog)


ui<- dashboardPage(
  #this gives you the name displayed on the tab
  dashboardHeader(title = "HHS Resin Purchasing 0.99"),
  #this gives you your sidebar (page) options
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Original Data", tabName = "original"),
      menuItem("Suggested", tabName = "suggested")
    )
  ),
  #this is the body of the webpages
  dashboardBody(
    #this gives you the body options that are displayed on every page
    fluidRow(
      column(width = 2,
    sidebarPanel(width = 2,
                 h2("Menu Options"),
                 h4(strong("Upload Data:")),
                 fileInput("file", "Data", buttonLabel = "Upload..."),
                 textInput("delim", "Delimiter (leave blank to guess)", ""),
                 numericInput("skip", "Rows to skip", 0, min = 0),
                 h4(strong("User Options:")),
                 selectInput("plant", "Select a Plant", choices =
                               c("All")),
                 dateInput("latest_date", "Select the latest W_LEAD date in the data",
                           value = Sys.Date()),
                 numericInput("avg_multiple", "Multiple of Daily Useage for Cuttoff",21, min = 1, max = 50),
                 h4(strong("Download Options:")),
                 actionButton("complete_orders", "Analysis for plant orders complete"),
                 actionButton("complete_checks", "Mid month check complete"),
                 downloadButton("downloadData1", label = "Download Suggested Orders...", class = "btn-block"),
                 downloadButton("downloadData2", label = "Download Flags...", class = "btn-block"),
                 downloadButton("downloadData3", label = "Download Full Suggested Orders Data...", class = "btn-block")
)
    ),
    #This is the actual data that fills those page options listed above
column(width = 6,   
 tabItems(
      tabItem(
              tabName = "original",
              DT::dataTableOutput("preview1",
                                  options = list(dom = 't', 
                                                 scrollX = TRUE, 
                                                 paging=FALSE,
                                                 fixedHeader=TRUE,
                                                 fixedColumns = list(leftColumns = 1, rightColumns = 0)))
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "suggested",
              box(title = "Suggested Orders",width = 9, status = "primary", height = "auto",
                  solidHeader = T, dataTableOutput("preview2"), style = "max-height:800px; overflow-y: scroll;overflow-x: scroll;")
      )
    )
)
)
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$preview1 <- renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(iris, options = list(searching = T, pageLength = 20, lengthMenu = c(5,10,15, 20)))
                      
  })
    
    output$preview2 <- renderDataTable({
      DT::datatable(iris, options = list(searching = T, pageLength = 20, lengthMenu = c(5,10,15, 20)))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```